# Ruby mixins and calling super methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok, so I've been refactoring my code in my little Rails app in an effort to remove duplication, and in general make my life easier (as I like an easy life).  Part of this refactoring, has been to move code that's common to two of my models to a module that I can include where I need it.

So far, so good. Looks like it's going to work out, but I've just hit a problem that I'm not sure how to get around.  The module (which I've called sendable), is just going to be the code that handles faxing, e-mailing, or printing a PDF of the document.  So, for example, I have a purchase order, and I have Internal Sales Orders (imaginatively abbreviated to ISO).

The problem I've struck, is that I want some variables initialised (initialized for people who don't spell correctly :P ) after the object is loaded, so I've been using the **after_initialize** hook. No problem... until I start adding some more mixins.

The problem I have, is that I can have an **`after_initialize`** in any one of my mixins, so I need to include a **super** call at the start to make sure the other mixin **`after_initialize`** calls get called.  Which is great, until I end up calling super and I get an error because there is no super to call.

Here's a little example, in case I haven't been confusing enough:

```
class Iso < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Shared::TracksSerialNumberExtension
  include Shared::OrderLines
  extend  Shared::Filtered
  include Sendable::Model

  validates_presence_of   :customer
  validates_associated    :lines

  owned_by                :customer
  order_lines             :despatched # Mixin

  tracks_serial_numbers   :items  # Mixin

  sendable :customer                      # Mixin

  attr_accessor :address

  def initialize( params = nil )
    super
    self.created_at ||= Time.now.to_date
  end
end
```

So, if each one of the mixins have an after_initialize call, with a **super** call, how can I stop that last **super** call from raising the error? How can I test that the super method exists before I call it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use this:

```
super if defined?(super)
```

Here is an example:

```
class A
end

class B < A
  def t
    super if defined?(super)
    puts "Hi from B"
  end
end

B.new.t
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `alias_method_chain`?  You can basically chained up all your `after_initialize` calls.  It acts like a decorator: each new method adds a new layer of functionality and passes the control onto the "overridden" method to do the rest.

Answer (score 3):

The including class (the thing that inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`, which, in this case is `Iso`) *could* define its own `after_initialize`, so any solution other than `alias_method_chain` (or other aliasing that saves the original) risks overwriting code.  @Orion Edwards' solution is the best I can come up with.  There are others, but they are **far** more hackish.

`alias_method_chain` also has the benefit of creating named versions of the after_initialize method, meaning you can customize the call order in those rare cases that it matters.  Otherwise, you're at the mercy of whatever order the including class includes the mixins.

*later*:

I've posted a question to the ruby-on-rails-core mailing list about creating default empty implementations of all callbacks.  The saving process checks for them all anyway, so I don't see why they shouldn't be there.  The only downside is creating extra empty stack frames, but that's pretty cheap on every known implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can just throw a quick conditional in there:

```
super if respond_to?('super')
```

and you should be fine - no adding useless methods; nice and clean.

Comment: This does **not** appear to work. respond_to?('super') will always return false.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than checking if the super method exists, you can just define it

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
    def after_initialize
    end
end
```

This works in my testing, and shouldn't break any of your existing code, because all your other classes which define it will just be silently overriding this method anyway

Comment: Downvoted because it is not a general solution. The point is you don't know whether or not the super exists, so monkeypatching ActiveRecord::Base#after_initialize into existence, you create a point where your code will break if/when ActiveRecord adds a Base#after_initialize, or its arity is changed; it is far beter to conditionally call it if it is defined.

Comment: @yaauie - sure, I could have put a `raise 'oh no' if methods.include?(:after_initialize)` before the monkeypatch, but that would make the example harder to understand... It's so easy to get caught up in detailing all the edge cases that the actual lesson here (just patch a base method in) would get lost in the noise.

Comment: monkeypatching is not a general solution and should not – in general – be encouraged. An answer that involves a one-off monekypatch that *may* happen to work leads to unnecessarily complex and fragile code, especially if you don't have control all the way up the inheritance chain.